# What is proper way to send app based on react-create-app to GitHub

Tags: javascript, git, reactjs, github

I'm creating an app based on react-create-app.
I want to send app sources to GitHub but question is: will other people be able to clone the repo and just run the application?

Are there any details to do before send to GitHub?

Comment: No I don't ask about public/private repo. I ask about some probably problems with using MYAPP BASED on react-create-app after cloning from repository.

Comment: clone it and do whatever you want with it

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Do you want other people to clone and run you application? Or do you not want people to clone it?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your app sources to be available to the public, you'll have to create a private repository. This option is not available to free accounts on Github.

Once that is created, you can follow the directions there to add it as a remote for your project.

Answer (score 0):

create a .gitignore file at root folder and add node_modules/ to it so that the 
 node_modules folder will be ignored and push as usual.

Github does not let you create private repository for free accounts. You can instead use BitBucket, which will let you create private repositories for free.

Comment: So there will not be any problems to run the application after cloning by other user? What about build scripts etc (will they be uploaded when pushing)?

Comment: After cloning it to another pc, run `npm install` in the terminal. it will install all the packages in your package.json file and it will run perfectly. The folder node_modules shouldn't be uploaded since it is pretty heavy, that is why you should have .gitignore file with `node_modules/` inside it. package.json file contains all the details of the data in node_modules folder